# How to format a minimum number of digits for a float in python

Tags: python

Is there an easy way to format a float so that there is at least one trailing digit, but allows for as many as are present? Desired output would be below:

```
x = function(1)
x = '1.0'

y = function(1.1)
y = '1.1'

z = function(1.2345)
z = '1.2345'
```

Using '%.1f' will add the trailing zero, but it will also clip any longer values. I can probably kludge together a small function that checks if the value is an integer and adds a '.0', but that seems un-pythonic.

```
def function(value):
    if int(value) == value:
        form_string = '%i.0' % value
    else:
        form_string = ('%f' % value).rstrip('0')

    return form_string
```

Thanks!

Comment: Floating point numbers don't have a concept of "how many are present".

Comment: `def function(a): return float(a)`, or if u really need the string, `def function(a): return str(float(a))`

Comment: What don't you understand from the `.format` documentation and previous questions?  "{:0.1}".format(value)

Comment: Keep in mind that `1` isn't a float. If you want to accept ints, doing so adds complexity, particularly for cases where `float(x) != x`.

Comment: @Prune: [That produces something very different from the desired output.](https://ideone.com/q8o51n)

Comment: @user2357112 `'%f' % 1` will convert 1 to a float to format it (which you can see pretty easily with `'%f' % 10**1000`). The bigger problem is the test in the other direction: where `int(float(x)) != float(x)`.

Comment: @abarnert: I'm thinking more along the lines of [this problem](https://ideone.com/zmOzQE), where the int's value isn't representable as a float.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, I suppose that's more insidious than `10**1000`, because you get a correct-looking but incorrect result, rather than an `OverflowError`…

Comment: Anyway, the short version is that `%`-formatting is not extensible, it doesn't have separate fields for min and max precision, and its "alternate form" rule for floats only guarantees a `.`, not a `.0`. So there is no way to do this without some kind of manual pre- or post-processing. And since post-processing is simpler and safer ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50141337/908494) is easy to understand, and can't screw anything up), that seems like the OOWTDI (to the extent that `%`-formatting is the right answer in the first place).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply convert to string and check if `.` is there?

```
def function(value):
    ret = str(value)
    if '.' not in ret:
        ret += '.0'
    return ret
```

Anyway, `str(float(value))` has the same effect, if you are dealing with *small* values (i.e. less than ~10<sup>15</sup>).

Comment: `str(float(value))` doesn't have the same effect. Try it with `10**1000`, `2**64+1`, etc. (Plus, if it _were_ true, that would make your answer worse than the two other answers, instead of better than them.)

Comment: The first little function seems more robust, but I'm going to be working with values definitely less than 10^10, so I'm not too worried about that flaw. 
Thanks for both ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an answer, for a fixed "I want at least one digit after the period" you just have to format it as float:

```
def parse(a):
    return str(float(a))
```